# Limiting the maximum amount of goroutines run simultaneously

Tags: asynchronous, concurrency, go

Here is my code which helps me to contol the maximum amount of goroutines run simultaneously.
In example below maximum is 5.

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
// Create bufferized channel with size 5
goroutines := make(chan struct{}, 5)
// Read data from input channel
for data := range input {
    // 1 struct{}{} - 1 goroutine
    goroutines <- struct{}{}
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(data string, goroutines <-chan struct{}, results chan<- result, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        // Process data
        results <- process(data)
        // Read from "goroutines" channel to free space for new goroutine
        <-goroutines
        wg.Done()
    }(data, goroutines, results, &wg)
}

wg.Wait()
close(goroutines)
```

Is there a better way to control the maximum amount of goroutines?
How can I improve my code?

Comment: this is correct. but inefficient because your code is performing `O(2n)` synchronizations that are not required if you would declare 5 permanent workers upfront. The runtime is built to handle millions routines, having 5 permanent workers, even sparingly consumed, is easy to handle for it and will prevent useless cpu usage. but again nothing wrong in your code.

Comment: I think your method the Best. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the Golang Concurrency Manager `goccm`](https://github.com/zenthangplus/goccm) to limit the maximum number of goroutines to run concurrently:

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "goccm"
    "time"
)

func main()  {
    // Limit 3 goroutines to run concurrently.
    c := goccm.New(3)

    for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {

        // This function have to call before any goroutine
        c.Wait()

        go func(i int) {
            fmt.Printf("Job %d is running\n", i)
            time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)

            // This function have to when a goroutine has finished
            // Or you can use `defer c.Done()` at the top of goroutine.
            c.Done()
        }(i)
    }

    // This function have to call to ensure all goroutines have finished 
    // after close the main program.
    c.WaitAllDone()
}
```